# Strange desktop blur out (Ubuntu 19 cinnamon desktop)

Tags: ubuntu, video, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, cinnamon

Ubuntu 19.04
Cinnamon Desktop
ASUS Nvidia GTX 1070 Turbo
2x1080p 24" monitors
1x1440p 32" monitors
i7-8700K (HT disabled)
16GB Ram
OS on Kingston NVMe M.2 256GB SSD

I'm getting a very strange blur out effect over all 3 of my screens intermittently.
Sometimes I never get it but like now, it's pulsing:
[Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjCFSgzdI5M)
[Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRds483XWbU)

what you see in the video's isn't the camera focus, it's what I am seeing on the desktop and on all applications opened.

What the *bleep* is happening?

Edit:
Found that switching to "Cinnamon Software Rendering" at login seems to keep it at bay but it is still a problem.